# Why does Gradle resolve a package with wrong version number?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jetty, dropwizard

I am building a web application and I am using Dropwizard 1.3.0, which has a dependency on jetty-io 9.4.8. This dependency has conflicts with another package (dropwizard-websocket-jee7-bundle 2.0.0), because it seem to fetch the wrong version number.

I looked into tha package, and found the method that has been renamed in [9.4.x - AbstractWebSocketConnection.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-common/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/common/io/AbstractWebSocketConnection.java#L647) from [9.3.x - AbstractWebSocketConnection.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-common/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/common/io/AbstractWebSocketConnection.java#L761). The issue is that even though in Gradle the dependency tree shows I fetched 9.4.8 (the new one which I need), I still get the older, 9.3.x java file which causes the conflicts. I tried to Invalidate Caches / Restart and rebuild the whole project, but I seem to get the outdated file all the time.

What are the possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bad class are imported by a transitive dependency, try to exclude explicit the transitive dependency.
For example if your required library is 'my.group:requiredLibrary:2.0.0' and there are another version in 'my.group:someDependency:0.1.5' you can do like this:

```
dependencies{
  compile 'my.group:requiredLibrary:2.0.0'
  compile ('my.group:someDependency:0.1.5'){
      exclude group: 'my.group'  module:'requiredLibrary'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a particular version in your build.gradle
Example here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html